# displaying image in table view which is saved in document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

i have saved image in document directory with following code and after it image is there in documentary directory successfully

```
UIImage *image =[[UIImage alloc ]init ];
 image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHolder.png"];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString: @"PlaceHolder.png"] ];
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

now i want to display image in table view
as in my table view some images are getting displayed from facebook url thats why i am using following code

```
NSString *path = [[_arrayForTable valueForKey:@"URL"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
AsyncImageView *imageView = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -5, 45, 45);
imageView.imageURL=url;
```

_arrayForTable is array of Dic and it includes URL some links are from facebook and some are from document directory

now my problem is as follows

** Only facebook images are getting displayed in table view but document directory images are not getting displayed**

i have checked location are perfectly correct for image but now displaying

Comment: put the code of image display from documents directory..

Comment: I have never used AsyncImageView class but from my experience, images that are found in a directory should be loaded using [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath].

Comment: but some images are getting displayed from url so how to do that some are from url and some are from uiimage ?

Comment: You dont need Async imageview even if its getting displayed from a url... u can directly display it

Comment: man then table view wont be smooth need lazy loding

Comment: I would firstly download them using NSURLConnection's asynchronous method which stores the image in an NSMutableData. You can then init the image with the mutable data.

Comment: as i am not so smart so its bit hard to catch you can you use answer than comment plz ?

Comment: Of course but I'm on the way to uni right now ... Give me an hour or two, okay? Sorry for that :/ btw that has absolutely nothing to do with being smart or not ;) it's just the idea you need ;)

Comment: ok man i am waiting for ur answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
```

This is wrong in your code. Replace it with this line of code.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

Check if file is exists in your documents directory or not

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

Also check in your documents directory if the image is getting saved or not. You are given the name of the image like this

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHolder.png"];
```

so if you are repeating this line your images will be overwritten in documents directory.

You can also put a check here
BOOL success = [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

```
if(success)
   NSLog(@"image written successfully");
else
   NSLog(@"image writing failed");
```

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

In your .m file

```
@interface YourClass ()<NSURLConnectionDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableData *receivedImageData;
@end

@implementation YourClass

- (void)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // Do your init stuff
        _receivedImageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    }
}

// A method to start your connection
- (void)startDownloadingImage {
    NSMutableURLRequest *downloadImageRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    downloadImageRequest.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.theImage.you/want/to/download.extension"];
    downloadImageRequest.HTTPMethod = @"GET";
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:downloadImageRequest delegate:self];

}

// You need the following delegate methods
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSURLConnection delegate methods

- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse {
    return request;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    // This method is called frequently ... you can see if you log
    // NSLog(@"I am downloading");
    [self.receivedImageData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Log an error or do whatever you want ;)
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // Create your picture here using
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.receivedImageData scale:1.0];
    // Only if there is an image display the downloaded image
    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(self.imageView.image.size, CGSizeZero)) {
        self.imageView.image = image;
    }
```

}

You could try to download the image, if there is no image you can keep displaying the PlaceHolder.png
Make sure you ***copied*** the image and it really is in your *project directory*

```
// self.imageView is an UIImageView
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHolder.png"];
[self startDownloadingImage];
```

Let me know if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the image data is not nil for the Document directory image?you have to retrieve the image by correct path and make sure that you are giving correct positions

Comment: i have checked there. there is image and yes path is perfectly correct

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncImageView` is a subclass of `UIImageView`. You can simply set the `image` property after you load the image using `initWithContentsOfFile:filePath`. You just have to figure out which images you want to load from the directory, and which ones from the web.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [[_arrayForTable valueForKey:@"URL"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
if ([path rangeOfString:documentsDirectory].location != NSNotFound)
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];

AsyncImageView *imageView = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -5, 45, 45);
imageView.imageURL=url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does  Asynchimageview support loading image from document directory or the bundle with image url??..Try to load an image from the bundle first. Recently i had a similar problem and ended up loading a placeholder from server itself.

Like in some other answers you can first create a `UIImage` object with `initWithContentsOfFile:`  set `asynchimageView.image`.